# How do I create a virtual host in Xampp?

Tags: xampp

Currently, the `Xampp DocumentRoot` is set to the project root of another computer. So I do not even know if `CordeIgniter` is installed properly.

So the way I found is to create a virtual host.

Is it hard to create that virtual host ?

How do I create a virtual host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First open your editor with **administrator privileges** so you can save files

Second go to

```
Windows > System32 > drivers > etc > vhost
```

You might see something like

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Under that create another one with your desired name

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       projectdesiredname.com
```

The go to

```
 xampp > appache > conf > extra > httpd-vhosts
```

On file you will see something like code below you can copy that one that is on there and paste it below and just modify like below here.

```
##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ##ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ##ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
##</VirtualHost>
```

As you can see I have removed some of `##`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/yourprojectfolder"
    ServerName projectdesiredname.com
    ##ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

> Save it and restart server

**Codeigniter**

Once thats done make sure you have set your base url in codeigniter config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://projectdesiredname.com/';
```

End base url with `/`

Comment: In the httpd.conf file, the DocumentRoot "C: \ Projects \ kisokihon_keisan / html" <Directory "C: \ Projects \ kisokihon_keisan / html"> ... </ Directory> Do not you have to edit this part or do you have to add this to the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

First, open the file C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts as administrator and add a new line

```
127.0.0.1 yournewsite.dev
```

Then, open [XAMPP PATH]\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf and add:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot C:/Sites/Yournewsite/
    ServerName yournewsite.dev
    <Directory "C:/Sites/Yournewsite/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also, in same file, you should have this line on the top of the file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

You should restart apache and put your website files in C:/Sites/Yournewsite/

Comment: In the httpd.conf file, the DocumentRoot "C: \ Projects \ kisokihon_keisan / html"
<Directory "C: \ Projects \ kisokihon_keisan / html">
  ... 
</ Directory>
Do not you have to edit this part or do you have to add this to the bottom?

Comment: If you use vhosts, apache will ignore that document root.